# Is there a way to map values from one dataframe to another in python?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe 1 with the following values:

| index | Sentence # | Word | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | In | O |
| 1 | 0 | the | O |
| 2 | 0 | summer | O |
| 3 | 0 | of | O |
| 4 | 0 | 2005 | O |
| 5 | 0 | , | O |
| 6 | 0 | a | O |
| 7 | 0 | picture | O |
| 8 | 0 | that | O |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 89 | 0 | summer | O |
| 90 | 0 | season | O |

And another dataframe 2:

| index | Word | Tag | Word Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | the summer of 2005 | DATE | 4 |
| 1 | Hong Kong | GPE | 2 |
| 2 | fifth | CARDINAL | 1 |
| 3 | summer season | SEASON | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I wanted to map Named-Entities from dataframe 2 to dataframe 1. Is there any way that we can achieve this?

For example, the output should look like:

| index | Sentence # | Word | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | In | O |
| 1 | 0 | the | DATE |
| 2 | 0 | summer | DATE |
| 3 | 0 | of | DATE |
| 4 | 0 | 2005 | DATE |
| 5 | 0 | , | O |
| 6 | 0 | a | O |
| 7 | 0 | picture | O |
| 8 | 0 | that | O |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 89 | 0 | summer | SEASON |
| 90 | 0 | season | SEASON |

Comment: Python doesn't _have_ dataframes. Presumably you are using pandas? Please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking questions about pandas as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Comment: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the dataframes as code

Comment: @gold_cy - That's not necessary. You can get the tables with `pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/71220955')[0]` (for the first table to `dataframe`)

Comment: we shouldn't have to be making API requests to SO to obtain the data. it should be provided as code in the body of the problem so that we can paste it in to the IDE

Comment: @gold_cy - I just wanted to know how we can map the phrase "the summer of 2005" and their tag as tokens to the first dataframe.

Comment: @shahzain - And you've been reminded to provide all the information in an easy-to-use format for anyone who wants to help you. I really like the table format, others don't.

Answer (score 1):

Split your column `Word` from your second dataframe into words then create a mapping dict (`Series`):

```
mapping = df2.assign(Word=df2['Word'].str.split()).explode('Word') \
             .set_index('Word')['Tag']

df1['Word'] = df1['Word'].map(mapping).fillna(df1['Tag'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   nSentence #     Word   Tag
0            0       In     O
1            0      the  DATE
2            0   summer  DATE
3            0       of  DATE
4            0     2005  DATE
5            0        ,     O
6            0        a     O
7            0  picture     O
8            0     that     O

>>> mapping
Word
the           DATE
summer        DATE
of            DATE
2005          DATE
Hong           GPE
Kong           GPE
fifth     Cardinal
Name: Tag, dtype: object
```

Note: if you have duplicated index entries, the code above will raise an exception:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: When I applied the code, I am actually getting this exception. How can we cater this exception?

Comment: The question is when you have 2 rows with 'summer' index for example, is the tag can be different for the two rows? In this case, which tag do you want to map with the word "summer"?

Comment: Yes, it can be different. For example, at one place 'summer' can be a DATE and at some instance 'summer' can be a 'SEASON'

Comment: So in `df1`, which tag do you want to set for the word "summer"? DATE or SEASON?

Comment: The column df2['Word'] is not the index column. Index column is the default integers from 0 to lenght of the df2.

Comment: In `df1` the tag should be based on what it was in `df2`.

Comment: What do you mean? The default index of `df2` is the `Sentence #` of `df1`?

Comment: I have edited the post so that you can understand it better.

Comment: Is the column `Sentence #` is relevant?

Comment: It is not relevant for this task but would be relevant for the next task that I have to perform.

Comment: I don't know how set the first "summer" word to DATE and the second to SEASON. Can you explain me, please?

Comment: The text in `df1` came from one long paragraph (which I converted into list by splitting them) and created a `df1`. Then, I also have a list of annotated word / pharases such as `df2`. I wanted to map the annotation from `df2` to `df1` and mark the remaining token as "O" 

So depending on the context of a sentence a token can be annotated differently. In our case, at one instance 'summer' is annotated as DATE and another 'summer' token as SEASON (keeping the previous token context into consideration)